# How to set fullHD image to ImageView

Tags: android

I want to set a fullHD(1080x1920) image to ImageView.
I have searched but no efficient method.

```
public static Bitmap decodeSampledBitmapFromResource(Resources res, int resId,
                                                     int reqWidth, int reqHeight) {

    // First decode with inJustDecodeBounds=true to check dimensions
    final BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
    BitmapFactory.decodeResource(res, resId, options);

    // Calculate inSampleSize
    options.inSampleSize = calculateInSampleSize(options, reqWidth, reqHeight);

    // Decode bitmap with inSampleSize set
    options.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
    return BitmapFactory.decodeResource(res, resId, options);
}

public static int calculateInSampleSize(
        BitmapFactory.Options options, int reqWidth, int reqHeight) {
    // Raw height and width of image
    final int height = options.outHeight;
    final int width = options.outWidth;
    Log.d("DUE","Options height: " + height + " - width: " + width);
    int inSampleSize = 1;

    if (height > reqHeight || width > reqWidth) {

        final int halfHeight = height / 2;
        final int halfWidth = width / 2;

        // Calculate the largest inSampleSize value that is a power of 2 and keeps both
        // height and width larger than the requested height and width.
        while ((halfHeight / inSampleSize) > reqHeight
                && (halfWidth / inSampleSize) > reqWidth) {
            inSampleSize *= 2;
        }
    }

    return inSampleSize;
}
```

Or:

```
private Bitmap resize(int resId, int width, int height){

    BitmapFactory.Options bmpFactoryOptions = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    bmpFactoryOptions.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
    Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), resId, bmpFactoryOptions);

    int heightRatio = (int)Math.ceil(bmpFactoryOptions.outHeight/(float)height);
    int widthRatio = (int)Math.ceil(bmpFactoryOptions.outWidth/(float)width);

    if (heightRatio > 1 || widthRatio > 1)
    {
        if (heightRatio > widthRatio)
        {
            bmpFactoryOptions.inSampleSize = heightRatio;
        } else {
            bmpFactoryOptions.inSampleSize = widthRatio;
        }
    }else{
    }

    bmpFactoryOptions.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
    bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), resId, bmpFactoryOptions);
    return bitmap;
}
```

I want to display the original image size, without reducing the size of image

Can you help me?

Thanks all!

Answer (score 1):

```
You can use image loading libraries like Universal Image Loader, Fresco.
1) https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader
2) https://github.com/facebook/fresco
3) https://guides.codepath.com/android/Displaying-Images-with-the-Fresco-Library
```

Answer (score 0):

Both examples you posted are useful to reduce the image size (i.e. to save memory).

> I want to display the original image size, without reducing the size of image

If you only want to set a image from resources, there are much simpler alternatives.

Assing the image in code to an ImageView:

```
ImageView img;
img.setImageResource(R.drawable.image);
```

Or create a Bitmap from your Resource:

```
Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.image);
```

Or set your image in xml:

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/image"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:src="@drawable/image"
    android:scaleType="center"/>
```

Comment: Seems too large image size.
It's always response:

Throwing OutOfMemoryError "Failed to allocate a 74649612 byte allocation with 399736 free bytes and 390KB until OOM"

Answer (score 0):

you can use **glide**

*[Glide](https://github.com/bumptech/glide) is a fast and efficient open source media management and image loading framework for Android that wraps media decoding, memory and disk caching, and resource pooling into a simple and easy to use interface.*

---

[full documantation](https://github.com/bumptech/glide/wiki)

---

[Downloading custom sizes with Glide](https://github.com/bumptech/glide/wiki/Downloading-custom-sizes-with-Glide)  **allow to add hight & width of iamge**

*Glide's ModelLoader interface provides developers with the size of the view they are loading an image into and allows them to use that size to choose a url to download an appropriately sized version of the image.
Using appropriately sized image saves bandwidth, storage space on the device, and improves the performance of the app.*